# FTP user privileges

Tags: windows-10, ftp, user-accounts, privileges

I need to create a user, who will be used solely for uploading files to FTP server on my windows 10 machine. Which user rights assignments and security options shall I give to this account in secpol.msc? In which options it should be included? The account should be able to upload data to the FTP server (not necessarily read them), and nothing else. I don't want the user to be in any builtin group, so I created a special group just for this account.

Answer (score 0):

The user accounts are given permissions through the
*Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager*,
where you can choose the permissions.

You need to allow Write for upload:

[image]

For detailed information, see the article
[How to set up and manage an FTP server on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-ftp-server-windows-10).

If the FTP folder is not the standard one allocated by IIS, you will need
to give IIS itself the necessary permissions on the folder,
where the account is normally called `IIS_IUSRS`.